# How to cause a "ORA-01555: snapshot too old error" without updates

Tags: oracle, jdbc, transactions

I am running into ORA-01555: snapshot too old errors with Oracle 9i but am not running any updates with this application at all.

The error occurs after the application has been connected for some hours without any queries, then every query (which would otherwise be subsecond queries) comes back with a ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 6 with name "_SYSSMU6$" too small.

Could this be cause of transaction isolation set to TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE? Or some other bug in the JDBC code? This could be caused by a bug in the [jdbc-go driver](https://github.com/japettyjohn/go-jdbc) but everything I've read about this bug has led me to believe scenarios where no DML statements are made this would not occur.

Comment: Are you absoluteley sure about: _"am not running any updates with this application at all"_? What application would that be? someone should write something in that database...

Comment: The application itself uses local MariaDB database for it's application specific information. The Oracle database is a data warehouse and is being accessed for read-only information from the perspective of this application, it is definitely being written to from other applications.

Answer (score 2):

Read below a very good insight on this error by Tom Kyte. The problem in your case may come from what is called '*delayed block cleanout*'. This is a case where selects creates redo. However, the root cause is almost sure improper size of rollback segments(but Tom adds as correlated causes: too frequently commits, a too big read after many updates, etc).

[snaphot too old error (Tom Kyte)](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:275215756923)

Comment: In my scenario I do no have direct control of the writes to the database. But if could be redo size in this case - I could take the query which is having issues and break it up into smaller queries, dealing with joins on the application side of things.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a query on an Oracle database the result will be what Oracle calls a "Read consistent snapshot".

What it means is that all the data items in the result will be represented with the value as of the the time the query was started.

To achieve this the DBMS looks into the rollback segments to get the original value of items which have been updated since the start of the query.

The DBMS uses the rollback segment in a circular way and will eventually wrap around - overwriting the old data.

If your query needs data that is no longer available in the rollback segment you will get "snapshot too old".

This can happen if your query is running for a long time on data being concurrently updated.

You can prevent it by either extending your rollback segments or avoid running the query concurrently with heavy updaters.

I also believe newer versions of Oracle provides better dynamic management of rollback segments than what is the case for Oracle 9i.